# Existence of toral subalgebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras

If $L$ is a semi-simple Lie algebra every element $x \in L$ has a Jordan decomposition into $x = x_s + x_n$ where $[x_s,x_n] = 0$ and $ad(x_s)$ is semi-simple while $ad(x_n)$ is nilpotent.

Thus if $L$ isn't nilpotent there is an $x \in L$ such that $ad(x_s) \neq 0$ and so the sub-algebra span$\{x_s\}$ is a toral sub-algebra.

In Humphrey's book he says that span$\{x_s : x \in L, x_s \neq  0\}$ is also a toral sub-algebra.

However, if $x, y \in L$, does it necessarily follow that $x_s + y_s$ is an ad-semi-simple element? I can't find a reason, for instance, that $x_s + y_s = (x+y)_s$.

> Why is span$\{x_s : x \in L, x_s \neq  0\}$ a toral sub-algebra?

Screen shot from Humphrey's book:
[image]

Comment: Good question. In general we don't have $x_s+y_s$ semisimple: e.g. $\pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}$ and $\pmatrix{0&0\\1&1}$ are both diagonalizable, but their sum is not.

Comment: @Berci right, thanks.. Probably just a mistake in the text.. He doesn't try to prove this, just states this in the introduction to the Root Space Decomposition chapter..

Comment: There might be special cases or more advanced reasons where/why it holds..

Comment: As stated, this is wrong; for every semisimple complex Lie algebra $L$, that span is actually all of $L$. Are you sure you quote Humphreys correctly? What is the exact phrasing and context in the book?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg added a screen shot

Answer (score 2):

As I read it, the text in the book just claims that the 1-dimensional subalgebra spanned by *one* nonzero $x_s$ is a non-zero subalgebra consisting of semisimple elements. (I agree the formulation is not completely clear.)

Comment: Ah, yes probably then..

Answer (score 0):

I believe that is a small mistake. As Andreas Cap said, that observation only implies that there is a 1-dimensional subalgebra consisting of semisimple elements.

The mistake is not even in the last [errata](https://www.springer.com/cda/content/document/cda_downloaddocument/Errata_Humphreys_Introduction_to_Lie_Algebras.pdf?SGWID=0-0-45-1590168-p1267745) of the book. Too bad Humphreys died from COVID 19 and that errata won't be updated anymore :(

However, this explained at some lenght and correctly in Erdmann, Karin; Wildon, Mark J. *Introduction to Lie algebras*, section 10.2 (note that the book calls maximal toral subalgebras Cartan subalgebras, but in the semisimple finite dimensional case these are the same):

> Let $L$ be a complex semisimple Lie algebra. We shall show that $L$ has a non-zero Cartan Subalgebra. We first note that $L$ must contain semisimple elements. If $x\in L$ has Jordan decomposition $x=s+n$, then by Theorem 9.15 both $s$ and $n$ belong to $L$. If the semisimple part $s$ were always zero, then by Engel's Theorem (in its second version), $L$ would be nilpotent and therefore solvable. Hence we can find a non-zero semisimple element $s\in L$. We can now obtain a non-zero Cartan Subalgebra $L$ by taking any subalgebra which contains $s$ and which is maximal subject to being abelian and consisting of semisimple elements. (Such a subalgebra must exists because $L$ is finite-dimensional.)